# Creating layer in group-layer in QGIS Graphical Modeler

Tags: pyqgis, layers, group-layer

I want the layers created during a graphic modeler process be stored in a specific layer group. I tried a bunch of stuff, based on clone-move-delete, node_root, layertreelayer... Maybe in alg_params just before the last output?

```py
from qgis.core import QgsProcessing
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingAlgorithm
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingMultiStepFeedback
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingParameterVectorLayer
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink
import processing

####Valeur initiale modifiée avec la campagne
Annee="2022"

###Définition du dossier agri
import os
root = os.getcwd()
if not os.path.exists(root+'/'+Annee+'/Trt_Qgis'):
    os.makedirs(root+'/'+Annee+'/Trt_Qgis')

class Trt_pise(QgsProcessingAlgorithm):
    
    def initAlgorithm(self, config=None):
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterString('Campagne', 'Campagne', multiLine=False, defaultValue=Annee))
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterVectorLayer('Annen', 'Annee n', types=[QgsProcessing.TypeVectorPolygon], defaultValue=None))
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterVectorLayer('Annen1', 'Annee n-1', types=[QgsProcessing.TypeVectorPolygon], defaultValue=None))
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink('ParcellaireFinal', 'Parcellaire final', type=QgsProcessing.TypeVectorAnyGeometry, createByDefault=True, defaultValue=None))

    def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, model_feedback):
        # Use a multi-step feedback, so that individual child algorithm progress reports are adjusted for the
        # overall progress through the model
        feedback = QgsProcessingMultiStepFeedback(2, model_feedback)
        results = {}
        outputs = {}

        # Union n/n-1
        alg_params = {
            'INPUT': parameters['Annen1'],
            'OVERLAY': parameters['Annen'],
            'OVERLAY_FIELDS_PREFIX': '',
            'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
        }
        outputs['UnionNn1'] = processing.run('native:union', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

        feedback.setCurrentStep(1)
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}

        # Nettoie parc final
        alg_params = {
            'EXPRESSION': '"SURF">0',
            'INPUT': outputs['UnionNn1']['OUTPUT'],
            'OUTPUT': parameters['ParcellaireFinal']
        }
        outputs['NettoieParcFinal'] = processing.run('native:extractbyexpression', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)
        results['ParcellaireFinal'] = outputs['NettoieParcFinal']['OUTPUT']
        return results

    def name(self):
        return 'Trt_PISE'

    def displayName(self):
        return 'Trt_PISE'

    def group(self):
        return ''

    def groupId(self):
        return ''
    def createInstance(self):
        return Trt_pise()
from qgis.core import *
root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
myGroup1 =root.insertGroup(0,Annee)
```