# Creating/choosing layer group in modeler using load layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler

Is there a workaround to be able to add the layer into a new or existing layer group?

I opened an issue with a feature request with more details
https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/54895

I saw this question:
[Creating layer in group-layer in QGIS Graphical Modeler](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/444593/creating-layer-in-group-layer-in-qgis-graphical-modeler)

But they seem to be Python focused, and I prefer a graphical solution if possible.